# Magento 2 disable merge items into the cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

HI I want customer add same item into cart with separate line. I don't want them merge together and into single line. Is there anyway to do this? I saw people asking for Magento 1, is there any solution for Magento 2? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote_Item" sortOrder="10" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class Item
{
    public function aroundRepresentProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $product
    ) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Quote\Item" />
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Quote/Item.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Quote;

class Item extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
{
    /**
     * Check product representation in item
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function representProduct($product)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to go for Option 2, I will give it a try and update you, thanks!

Comment: Above solution works great, exactly what I need